# Can't "ember server" but "npm start" works

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Although I successfully installed ember-cli, I cannot run `ember server`. It said `-bash: ember: command not found`. But when I ran `npm start`, that worked.

According to the `package.json` file, `npm start` is referring to `ember server`.
But why didn't `ember server` work?

Comment: It sounds like you installed Ember-CLI only *locally* in your package. Did you install it with `npm install -g ember-cli`?

Comment: 100% sure I installed it globally. Do I need to add PATH for it?

Comment: Yeah, you might have to add the path to NPM's bin folder to your PATH, although any globally installed binaries like `ember` from package `ember-cli` should be linked to a location on your path automatically: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html. Can you find the `ember` executable on your filesystem?

Comment: my npm's path is /Users/Hao/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/npm is this related?

Comment: I switch to root `sudo -i` to run `npm install -g ember-cli` After that, `ember server` works. But it throws an error: watch ENOENT

Error: watch ENOENT
    at errnoException (fs.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1051:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1076:11)
    at Watcher.watchdir (/Users/Hao/Documents/Study/OnlineCourse/WebDev/Projects/hacknews1/hack-journalism-team-phd/ember/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-sane-watcher/node_modules/sane/index.js:184:20)

Answer (score 1):

The way I fixed this problem is by running `ember init` in the repo, and let it override all the testing related files and skip all the files related to the project, like routes/app.js.

Oh, Yeah~

Comment: except I would imagine that if ember cannot be found then ember init probably wont be found either.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you may have installed npm or another part of the node toolchain with `sudo`. Here are some common ways to install the toolchain--I can say from experience that avoiding using sudo in package managers (and everything possible) is often the way to go.

Hope this helps--let us know if it was something else.

Comment: I remove ~/.npm ~/.nvm and /user/lib/node_modues and re-installed nodejs and nvm. Then I cloned an existing ember-cli project and ran `ember init`.And then I was asked to override some files, like app/router.js. If I choose `Y`, the server will start but with some error like "Ember is not defined", "DS is not defined", though hitting the http://0.0.0.0:4200/ looks fine. If I choose 'N', it wont override the files. But it will throw errors: watch ENOENT
Error: watch ENOENT
    at errnoException (fs.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1051:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1076:11)

Comment: I would start with creating a new project per their instructions. Can you do `node -v`? If the node version isn't chose, it won't find `ember`, so you may need to `nvm use [your_version]`. (Also, to run an existing project, you'll need to `npm install` and `bower install` before `ember s`)